# Incorrect characters in first cell of CSV output file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

When database is exported in CSV format, I get this as the first column name: ÔªøId. The output is the same on different computers and operating systems. The rest of the data is correct. The database is created in ActivaAdmin, RoR. What could cause this? no need to explain that I need Id as a column name.

Comment: What language is the data and column names in - English?

Comment: The database is in English, and I do not know what character set encoding is...

Comment: Make sure your data is clean. I mean, it maybe some entry in a record. Also try exporting as SQL lines instead of CSV and see if you get any entry like the one you've mentioned.

Comment: ActiveAdmin allows to export in  XML and JSON format. Only CSV has this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a [UTF-8 BOM (Byte Order Mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8), (although strictly speaking there is no need for a byte order in UTF-8).

While the characters you show are different, there are exactly 3 bytes at the beginning of your file (and maybe these are converted with copy/paste or reading of the file).

Answer (score 0):

Use `:type => 'text/csv; charset=<charset>; header=present'` in `send_data` method.

Like, Assuming you've `customer` model and need to export all `customers` then

```
  def export_customers
    @customers = Customer.all
    c = CSV.generate_line(["S.No", "Name", "About", "Phone", "Address", "City", "State", "Country"], :col_sep => ', ', :row_sep => "\r\n", :quote_char => '"')
    @customers.each_with_index do |customer, index|
      c += CSV.generate_line([index + 1, customer.name, customer.about, customer.phone, customer.address, customer.city, customer.state, customer.country], :col_sep => ', ', :row_sep => "\r\n", :quote_char => '"')
    end

    send_data(c, :type => 'text/csv; charset=<charset>; header=present', :filename => 'customers.csv')
end
```

Comment: Why do you suggest using the 'iso-8859-1' charset? I'd go for whatever clonecq uses in their database. (Preferrably 'utf-8')

Comment: i never done generating csv files like that, I will try your solutions and post back.

Comment: I used ActiveAdmin built-in _expot to CSV_ link. Your reply made me think that there is something wrong with ActiveAdmin code, but I did not come across any similar problems reported